# Number elements by class and get placement of specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list like this:

```
<div class="list"></div>
<div class="list"></div>
<div class="list on"></div>
<div class="list"></div>
... etc
```

I get the total like this:

```
var count = $('.list').length; // 4 in this case
```

But I want to write a function that selects the next div with the down arrow, and I can't figure out how to get the next div, select it, and deselect the current div. This is what I have now, but it doesn't work:

```
var visible = $('.list:visible');
var on = $('.list.on:visible');
if (e.keyCode == 40) { // down key
    if(on.length == 0) {
        visible.first().addClass("on"); // this works
    }
    else if( // div placement // < count) {
        var next = on.next(); // this part doesn't work
        on.removeClass("on"); // :(
        next.addClass("on"); // :(
    }
    else { // if its the last div
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
if (e.keyCode == 40) { // down key
    if(on.length == 0) {
        visible.first().addClass("on");
    }
    else if(on.length && on.next("div.list").length > 0) {
        var next = on.next("div.list");
        on.removeClass("on");
        next.addClass("on");
    }
    else { // if its the last div
    // do nothing
    }
}
```

A quick demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GL7tA/

Comment: This works until you introduce a hidden element into the list? http://jsfiddle.net/GL7tA/1/

Comment: @user2250471-- Use the `:visible` selector then

Comment: I tried the :visible selector. Apparently next()/prev() ignores the selector, so it didn't work. I ended up using a different class for hidden list items (instead of .hide();) and .nextAll('.list:first').addClass("on"); to get it fully working because it was still buggy. But your answer pointed me down the right path, so I'll give you the credit. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can work with `.index()` to see which item is currently "selected":

```
var $items = $('.list:visible'),
$selectedItem = $items.filter('.on'),
selectedIndex = $items.index($selectedItem);

if (selectedIndex == -1) {
  $items.eq(0).addClass('on');
} else if (selectedIndex + 1 < $items.length) {
  $selectedItem.next().andSelf().toggleClass('on');
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You have a syntax error in `the else if (` part, where you say it doesn't work.

It doesn't work because the `else if` is expecting a condition to evaluate but you are not even closing the parenthesis of that `if` condition, neither have you openned the brackets for its block.

Comment: Also, try to check your javascript code in a javascript console so you can see if you have syntax errors or execute it live in a web page to see if it works. I would recommend you firefox's scratchpad, firebug's console, chrome dev tools console or operas' dragonfly